# What happens when an answer crosses the threshold of originality, but the code within that answer doesn't?

Tags: discussion, licensing, creative-commons, mit

Here's a hypothetical situation.

I post an answer on a Stack Exchange site. In order to be useful, the post requires both English prose and code. However, the code alone does not cross the [threshold of originality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_of_originality). The prose text alone also does not cross the threshold of originality. Only the combined work expresses a "minimal degree of creativity".

How does this work? Is the whole post (prose + code) available under CC BY-SA? Can someone take one facet (the text or the code) and replace the other and take it as their own work? Can someone use the code in any situation with no concern? How about the text?

Comment: As you tagged this with [tag:mit], do you wonder how that would be handled if the code is licensed under MIT (like proposed?) instead of CC BY-SA (like it’s currently the case)?

Comment: @unor Both instances.